# Pandas - Trying to combine data from multiple rows into a single row based on a common key

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe in the below format:

```
cust_id, sales
101, apple:1
101, banana:2
102, apple:1
103, apple:3
103, banana:5
103, apple:7
```

I am trying to have all the sales data by cust_id in a single row. Sometimes the same cust_id can also have multiple sales for the same product. For such entries I would like to have a new column created.

This is how I expect the final output to be:

```
cust_id, apple, banana, apple
101, 1, 2
102, 1,
103, 3, 5, 7
```

Comment: Given that your expected final output includes two columns of the same name (apple & apple), do you have a preferred work around for this?  E.g. apple_1, apple_2.  I ask this as Pandas does not like having multiple columns with the same name.

Comment: @IanLogie, I would prefer it to have the same label but having a prefix wouldn't hurt either.. so having labels such as apple_1 and apple_2 would be fine as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split `sales` column to multiple columns. Use `groupby.cumcount` to separate duplicated names and use `pd.crosstab` to achieve the final result

```
df1 = df.set_index('cust_id').sales.str.split(':', expand=True)
s = df1.groupby(['cust_id', 0]).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')
df_final = pd.crosstab(df1.index, df1[0]+s, df1[1], aggfunc='first')

Out[111]:
col_0 apple apple1 banana
row_0
101       1   None      2
102       1   None   None
103       3      7      5
```

**Note**: pivoting table always sorts column names, so the output dataframe has its column names sorted